# Cannot import example dataset (the system cannot find the specified file)

Tags: mongodb

I am following the example given on MongoDB's website [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/import-data/), but I am running into trouble when trying to import sample data.

When running the command

```
mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file primer-dataset.json
```

I get the error:

> Failed: open primer-dataset.json: The system cannot find the file specified

The problem is, I am not sure what directory MongoDB expects this file to be in. I tried placing it in data/db, but that did not work. Note that I am only using default settings.

I know this is a somewhat trivial question and I feel stupid for asking it but I can not find documentation on this anywhere. Where is MongoDB expecting import files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB expects the file to be in the directory from where you are running the command mongoimport.

If you place your file under data/db then set mongodb path as global environment variable and execute the command from data/db directory.

Additionally if you have security enabled for your mongodb then you need to execute command as below

> **mongoimport --username admin --password password --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file primer-dataset.json**

here admin is the user authorized to perform db operations for test database and restaurants is the collection name.

Comment: Actually, you can place the file anywhere on the system, just use the full file path and file name in quotes.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows!
Save file using notepad++ in .json format at MongoDB/bin where mongoimport command is present.

Simple notepad has trouble doing it.

Comment: This worked for me! i saved the file using notepad++ in .json format. You can use your full file path. my path was **C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\primer-dataset.json** and my code `mongoimport --db test --collection restu
rants --drop --type json --file C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\primer-dataset.json`

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well. The issue was that though the file was visible as restaurants.json actually the file was restaurants.json.json (since saved in JSON format). The issue was resolved after properly changing the name.

Comment: Maybe leave this as a comment instead

Answer (score 0):

i have trouble like you, check you path to file, mongoimport.exe and your file may be stay in another folders.[image]

use  `mongoimport -d test1 -c restaraunts companies.json` for import to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Check the filename extension, and make sure it's a ".json" file;
After this I successfully run the

> mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file [path\to\Json file]

command;

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed the `--drop` parameter and it worked perfectly. I guess, it is throwing this error:

> Failed: open paht/file-name.json: The system cannot find the file specified.

because the collection it wants to drop is not available, because I have not created any before.

Answer (score 0):

you must copy your json file into C:\Windows\System32 and write this command on cmd:
mongoimport --db test --collection mongotest --type json --file yournamefile.json